# Wordpress - adding pseud-class before to footer element

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i tried to add some extra bckground before footer with this code:

```
#main-footer::before {
   content: " ";
   background: url("/bottom.png") no-repeat;
   background-size: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   height: 140px;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

But element hang somewhere in the middle of website. Can you please help me understand why it so and what im doing wrong here ? 
Here is url : http://webconcept.hekko24.pl/mr/

Comment: Can you please supply your HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to your `#main-footer`.

Absolute positioned elements need have relative parent to get its sizes.

Comment: Ok it somehow resolve problem , thank you - now another issue pop-up. element is flowing on footer, is there any way to keep it right before footer start and be RWD in the same time ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. Try to add a new question

Answer (score -1):

`position: absolute` removes your element from the document flow thus it behaves independent of all other elements.
Try changing that to `position: relative`.
If that doesn't solve it why not use the easier method of using the `<br>` tag or `&nbsp;`